# URL with Hash to be Clean URL

Tags: jquery, html, url, hashtag

can someone please help me with this
I want to make a url like this

```
http://www.website.com/#contactus
```

and would become and display a clean URL like this

```
http://www.website.com/contactus
```

but it will function the same as the hash url. Like when i include some jquery slides to it..

when i click

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/contactus">Contact Us</a>
```

it would slide to the div with id of contactus

```
<div id="contactus"></div>
```

without refreshing the page but it would change the url.

What tools will i use. Please guide me thank in advance. :)

Comment: If contactus is on the same page, you should use `#contactus`, not some fancy url. If the contactus page is a seperate page, you can possibly use the history api, but it is out-of-scope to give you a complete tutorial on how to use that. In any case, `.htaccess` is something server-side, and I don't see how it is related to your problem.

Comment: how would i do that @Juhana

Comment: [Here are the instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/#(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

/contact us sends you to the index.html/php or whatever in a folder called contact, but you could try some things using

```
return false
```

good luck!